# Mobile API Security Paradigm

Tags: security, api, node.js, https, webserver

I've coded the mobile api using **Node.js, Redis** & **MongoDB**. However right now I am looking for a **concrete way** to provide security in our system. The question I have inspired by the infamous principle of Auguste Kerckhoff;

*"It must not be required to be secret, and it must be able to fall into the hands of the enemy without inconvenience"*

After inspecting this principle I figure out that there is **no safe way** to secure data after a sniffer capturing the entire data package. Of course there are alternate ways like using an **API key**, using **encryption algorithms** like **MD5 & MD6**,**Triple DES**,**SHA1** etc. However this also won't work if the entire data package is captured. And there is security precaution standarts like **HTTPS, SSL certificates**. However again if someone with talent captures the data package it can act just like a verified user in our system.

How would it be possible to apply a security method such that even though the entire data package is captured, the system would be able to distinguish the request coming from an outer source not from our verified user.

**PS:**  I thought that applying a custom encryption algorithm with timestamp in order to prevent this problem could be a bit chaotic.

Comment: What's wrong with HTTPS? With properly validated HTTPS, there is no middle-man.

Answer (score 1):

According to Kerckhoffs's principle "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge." So the way cryptosystem, works is that the key is the only thing that can be used to decipher the system. If the key is fallen to the enemy then its all over.

> In practice when you communicate over the internet or try to
>   authenticate your email account with the password. Your password is
>   never sent to, nor stored on the server in plain text. If you do then,
>   its not secure. The best security practice is not to store the
>   password at all (not even encrypted), but to store the salted hash of
>   the encrypted password.

That is one hash for one user. It is one way, you cannot get back user info, just test if it is in the database or not. Now even if the enemy takes control of the database, it cannot access your username/passwords.

Now coming to the point, it does not matter what you transmit in the communication channel, because the communication channel is the enemy!!! It is available to other users, anyone can sniff it. It is like enemies scanning each other on the radio.

The hash that has been sent over the channel can be sniffed and be used for authentication. True, but server can differentiate between spoofed attempt and the actual attempt, using HTTPS connection. Server tracks the HTTPS sessions and would ask to revalidate if something like this happens. HTTPS blocks use of sniffed data / MITM attacks. Even if sniffer gets hash (temporary ticket), he cannot do anything malicious, username and password cannot be cracked.

Thanks to Kerckhoff, our passwords are safe.

How to implement it on node.js ?? look for passport.js package. It implements the current standard OpenAuth.